# the signature of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^{2,2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

can someone explain to me what is a signature of a plane (subspace of dimension 2) in $\mathbb{R}^{2,2}$

i read that the intesection in $\mathbb{R}^{2,2}$ of a plane and the set $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb{R}^4|-x_1-x_2+x_3+x_4=-1\}$ has the signature (0,2),(1,1)or (0,1) why not (1,0) or (2,0) ??!!
thanks for every answer

Answer (score 0):

By Sylvester's Law of Inertia, for a bilinear form $g : \Bbb V \times \Bbb V \to \Bbb R$ on a real vector space $\Bbb R$ there is a basis of $V$ with respect to which the matrix representation of $g$ has the form
$$\operatorname{diag}(\underbrace{1, \ldots, 1}_{n_+}, \underbrace{0, \ldots, 0}_{n_0}, \underbrace{-1, \ldots, -1}_{n_-}) .$$
In general there are many such bases but the triple $(n_+, n_0, n_-)$ does not depend on $g$, that is, depends only on the form. This triple is the *signature* of $g$. Usually one only works with nondegenerate forms, that is, forms for which $n_0 = 0$ (equivalently, so that the map $\flat : \Bbb V \to \Bbb V^*$, $\flat(X)(Y) := g(X, Y)$ is an isomorphism), in which case we often just write $(n_+, n_-)$.

Checking shows that the restriction $g\vert_{\Pi}$ of $g$ to a linear subspace $\Pi \subseteq \Bbb V$ is again a symmetric bilinear form, but unless $g$ is definite (that is, $n_- = n_0 = 0$ or $n_+ = n_0 = 0$), for some choices of $\Pi$ that restriction will be degenerate. In the context of the question, the **signature** of the subspace $\Pi$ here surely refers to the signature of $g\vert_{\Pi}$.

If $g$ is nondegenerate, say, it has signature $(n_+, n_-)$, and $\dim \Pi = m$, then the signatures of $\Pi$ that occur are the triples $(m_+, m_0, m_-)$ of nonnegative triples of integers satisfying $m_+ + m_0 + m_- = m$ and $m_0 + m_{\pm} \leq n_{\pm}$. So, in the case of $\Bbb R^{2, 2}$, for which $h$ has signature $(2, 2)$, the possible signatures of $2$-planes $\Pi$ are $$\underbrace{\overbrace{(2, 0, 0)}^{\begin{array}{c}{\textrm{positive}\\ \textrm{definite}}\end{array}}, (1, 0, 1), \overbrace{(0, 0, 2)}^{\begin{array}{c}{\textrm{negative}\\ \textrm{definite}}\end{array}}}_{\textrm{nondegenerate}}, \underbrace{(1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), \overbrace{(0, 2, 0)}^{\textrm{zero form}}}_{\textrm{degenerate}}.$$

Comment: thanks travis and orangeskid, i read that the intesection in $\mathbb{R}^{2,2}$ of a plane and the set $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb{R}^4|-x_1-x_2+x_3+x_4=-1$ has the signature (0,2),(1,1)or (0,1) why not (1,0) or (2,0) ??!!

Comment: I'm puzzled by your statement: Such an intersection is an affine plane but not a subspace (i.e., it does not contain the zero vector), so by definition the restriction of $g$ to that intersection is *not* a bilinear form. In any case, to answer whatever that question may be, since you refer to specific coordinates on $\Bbb R^{2, 2}$ you'd need to say *which* bilinear form you mean. orangeskid's answer gives on such form, but there are (infinitely) many others possible.

Comment: the bilinear form is $<(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4),(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)>=-x_1y_1-x_2y_2+x_3y_3+x_4y_4$

Comment: why in orageskid's answer we have $<e_3,e_3>=<e_4,e_4>=1$ and <e_1,e_1>=<e_2,e_2>=-1?

Comment: That is simply how he chose to define his bilinear form. (Conveniently, it coincides with the bilinear form you mentioned.)

Answer (score 0):

You consider a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^4$ of signature $(2,2)$ and the restriction of this form subspace of dimension $2$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$. What is the signature of this form? It can be pretty much whatever is allowed by numbers. Say we have the bilinear symmetric form ( quadratic form) with an orthogonal basis $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$, $e_4$, $\langle e_i, e_j \rangle = 0$ for $i\ne j$, and also $\langle e_3, e_3\rangle = \langle e_4, e_4\rangle= 1$,  $\langle e_1, e_1\rangle = \langle e_2, e_2\rangle= -1$.

Here are some examples pairs of spanning vectors for $V$'s

$(e_1+e_3, e_2+e_4)$ :  the restriction is the $0$ form

$(e_1+e_3, e_4)$ : positive semidefinite, degenerate

$(e_1+e_3, e_2)$ : negative semidefinite, degenerate.

Comment: what always $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$  satisfy $<e_3,e_3>=<e_4,e_4>=1$ and  $<e_1,e_1>=<e_2,e_2>=-1$ ?